# get email recipient's first and last name in Cloud Page with SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ssjs, cloudpage

I'm using CloudpagesURL(xxxx) in an email to link to a SFMC Cloud Page when the CTA is clicked.

How can I get the first and last name of the email recipient in the cloudpage with SSJS? Do I have to pass them along from the email in the CloudPagesURL(xxxx) and then retrieve once in the Cloud Page?

None of the recipients are on a publication list (I assume I cannot use any of the subscriber functions in the SSJS documentation).

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need SSJS to achieve this. I will assume you have a main Data Extension where all your contacts are present. You could pass the Subscriber Key in your CloudPagesURL and use the [Lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm) function to retrieve name and other fields you might find necessary from that Data Extension.

Comment: Thank you Lucas - I'm going to do the same thing you suggested but use the SSJS functions to look them up in the DE. :-)
I have to use SSJS anyways because I have a custom form that I need to pull data from to update the DE the recipient are on.

Comment: You are welcome, Paulette. Remember to mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I find it's easier to set them in Ampscript when the page loads by doing as Lukas said - pass the subscriber key in (I'd recommend using [Base64](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Base64Encode.htm) to encode it, then decode on the page) and then use [Lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm) to find the first and last names from whichever DE you have them saved in.

You can then set these variables and retrieve them within your SSJS form using [GetValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_utilitiesVariableGetValue.htm).